# iOS : NSString Evaluate String Expression

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring

I have large XML file ( almost 1,27,000 ) bank records.

In one scenario we needed to check Bank Names. e.g.

```
if(
        [title isEqualToString:@"ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED" ] ||
                   [title isEqualToString:@"ABU DHABI COMMERCIAL BANK" ] ||
                   [title isEqualToString:@"AHMEDABAD MERCANTILE COOPERATIVE BANK" ] ){
////Perform certain action
}
```

Currently we have XML structure and we are parsing this huge data into NSString. So I get above sample data in NSString object.

How to evaluate NSString for above example? On stack overflow found lot of examples of using **NSPredicate** and **NSExpression**. But with my understanding of those questions they will handle math expression e.g. 4/3 * 2 etc.. I was unable to process above format using those examples.

Is there way to evaluate above format in NSString and if condition?

**PS** - Was able to solve above problem by converting data into database but looking for NSString evaluation for String format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is only about making your expression nicer and not changing the underlying logic, you can do this:

```
NSArray <NSString *> *bankNames = @[@"ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED" 
                                    @"ABU DHABI COMMERCIAL BANK",
                                    @"AHMEDABAD MERCANTILE COOPERATIVE BANK"];
if ([bankNames contains:title]) {
    //Perform certain action
}
```

If you insist on using predicates, then you should do sth like this:

```
NSArray <NSString *> *bankNames = @[@"ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED" 
                                    @"ABU DHABI COMMERCIAL BANK",
                                    @"AHMEDABAD MERCANTILE COOPERATIVE BANK"];
NSPredicate *containsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicate:@"%K equals %@", @"SELF", title];
BOOl matchesName = [bankNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate].count > 0;
```

Nevertheless, I don't really understand why you would want to do that.

Comment: yes this is good alternative. I'll mark this as answer. Is there way to Evaluate NSString in obj-c?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Comment: If i get [title isEqualToString:@"ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED" ] ||
                   [title isEqualToString:@"ABU DHABI COMMERCIAL BANK" ] ||
                   [title isEqualToString:@"AHMEDABAD MERCANTILE COOPERATIVE BANK" ] data in this format. Can I use NSEXpression NSPredicate to evaluate String at run time?

Comment: No.  On OS X, you could potentially link libclang and do compiling and execution at runtime, but there's no option for that on iOS.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve with NSPredicate and NSExpression, that would not be solved with my initial solution. Nevertheless, I updated my answer, hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Let you have the Data in an `NSArray`, named `response`, which you want to filter according to the condition.

```
    NSArray *expectedBanks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                      @"ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED" ,
                                                      @"ABU DHABI COMMERCIAL BANK" ,
                                                      @"AHMEDABAD MERCANTILE COOPERATIVE BANK", nil];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bank IN %@", expectedBanks];
        NSArray *filtered  = [response filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The above code snippet assumes that key  for the object ,we need to search in the Array is "bank"